# Voronoi regions of lattices with dimensions $\leq 16$

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, lattice-crypto

Is there any idea about calculating the exact Voronoi regions of lattices with dimensions $\leq 16$?

Thank you!

Comment: That would depend of what you are starting from!

Comment: By "lattices" here do you mean "$q$-ary lattices" (as are common in cryptography), or all lattices (up to equivalence, usually by multiplication by $\mathsf{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ on the right and $O_n(\mathbb{R})$ on the left)?

Answer (score 1):

Micciancio and Voulgaris [https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~pvoulgar/files/voronoi_full.pdf] gave a $\tilde O(4^n)$ algorithm to computer Voronoi relevant vectors, which should be reasonable for $n=16$.

However, this may be painful to implement exactly this algorithm. Though an important remark of that paper is that you can you can deduce the $2^n$ Voronoi relevant vector by solving CVP, relatively to the $2^n$ cosets of $\frac 1 2 L$ in $L$.